# How to make hidden directories visible in Aptana Studio?

Tags: aptana-studio

I did all actions described here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166755/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-aptanas-project-view

And i can see files that start with `.` like `.htaccess` etc, but for example I still can't see `.git` folder in my project browsers in Aptana. Is it even possible to make Aptana Studio detect hidden folders in projects directory?

Comment: Let us start with the basics.  Which version of Aptana?  Clearly its possible since the linked question has several answers explaining how to do it.

Comment: I'm using latest version that i've downloaded an hour ago. To be exact:```Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044```

Comment: Feel free to update your question.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You forgot to indicate the version of the software in your question.  There is an edit feature for a reason.